# Audio element is coming above the fixed element

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, deployment

I am trying to build a  webpage with a religious hymn and with some audio, on smaller screens, the audio element is coming above the side panel. I had tried using z-index but it didn't work.

This is my code:

```js
const icon = document.getElementById('icon');
const side = document.getElementById('side');

icon.addEventListener('click', () => {
    side.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap');
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: rgb(196, 196, 196);
}

header{
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #aaaaaa;
}

.heading{
    margin-inline:auto ;
}

.heading h1{
    margin: 0.8rem;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
}

.side-panel{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    transform: translateX(-23rem);
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.icon{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 5;
    width: auto;
    top: 1.2rem;
    left: 2rem;
}

.link{
    margin: 5rem 1rem;
}

.side-panel li{
    list-style: none;
    margin-block: 1rem;
    padding: 10px 8px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: #dadada;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
}

.side-panel li:hover{
    border: 2px solid #aaaaaa;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.side-panel li a{
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.active{
    transform: translateX(0rem);
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.container{
    display: flex;
    margin-block: 3.6rem;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

audio{
    z-index: -1;
}

.container h1,p{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
hr{
    width: 90%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.mantra{
    word-spacing: 1.2rem;
    font-size: large;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .mantra{
        word-spacing: normal;
    }
    .active{
        width: 100%;
    }
    .side-panel li a{
        font-size: 1rem;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Strotam</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <div class="heading">
            <h1>STROTAM</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="icon" id="icon">
            <img width="32" height="32" src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-filled/50/menu--v1.png" alt="menu--v1"/>
        </div>
        <div class="side-panel" id="side">
            <div class="link" >
                <li><a href="#">Dwadash Jyotirlinga Stotram</a></li>
            </div>
        <div/>
    </header>
    
    <!-- Main start -->

    <div class="container">
        <h1>द्वादश ज्योतिर्लिङ्ग स्तोत्रम् </h1>
        <hr>
        <audio controls >
            <source src="https://samplelib.com/lib/preview/mp3/sample-15s.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>
        <p>Listen while reading</p>
        <br>
        <p class="mantra">
            सौराष्ट्रदेशे विशदेऽतिरम्ये ज्योतिर्मयं चन्द्रकलावतंसम् ।
            <br>
            भक्तिप्रदानाय कृपावतीर्णं तं सोमनाथं शरणं प्रपद्ये ॥1
            <br><br>
            श्रीशैलशृङ्गे विबुधातिसङ्गे तुलाद्रितुङ्गेऽपि मुदा वसन्तम् ।
            <br>
            तमर्जुनं मल्लिकपूर्वमेकं नमामि संसारसमुद्रसेतुम् ॥2
            <br><br>
            अवन्तिकायां विहितावतारं मुक्तिप्रदानाय च सज्जनानाम् ।
            <br>
            अकालमृत्योः परिरक्षणार्थं वन्दे महाकालमहासुरेशम् ॥3
            <br><br>
            कावेरिकानर्मदयोः पवित्रे समागमे सज्जनतारणाय ।
            <br>
            सदैवमान्धातृपुरे वसन्तमोङ्कारमीशं शिवमेकमीडे ॥4
            <br><br>
            पूर्वोत्तरे प्रज्वलिकानिधाने सदा वसन्तं गिरिजासमेतम् ।
            <br>
            सुरासुराराधितपादपद्मं श्रीवैद्यनाथं तमहं नमामि ॥5
            <br><br>
            याम्ये सदङ्गे नगरेऽतिरम्ये विभूषिताङ्गं विविधैश्च भोगैः ।
            <br>
            सद्भक्तिमुक्तिप्रदमीशमेकं श्रीनागनाथं शरणं प्रपद्ये ॥6
            <br><br>
            महाद्रिपार्श्वे च तटे रमन्तं सम्पूज्यमानं सततं मुनीन्द्रैः ।
            <br>
            सुरासुरैर्यक्ष महोरगाढ्यैः केदारमीशं शिवमेकमीडे ॥7
            <br><br>
            सह्याद्रिशीर्षे विमले वसन्तं गोदावरितीरपवित्रदेशे ।
            <br>
            यद्धर्शनात्पातकमाशु नाशं प्रयाति तं त्र्यम्बकमीशमीडे ॥8
            <br><br>
            सुताम्रपर्णीजलराशियोगे निबध्य सेतुं विशिखैरसंख्यैः ।
            <br>
            श्रीरामचन्द्रेण समर्पितं तं रामेश्वराख्यं नियतं नमामि ॥9
            <br><br>
            यं डाकिनिशाकिनिकासमाजे निषेव्यमाणं पिशिताशनैश्च ।
            <br>
            सदैव भीमादिपदप्रसिद्दं तं शङ्करं भक्तहितं नमामि ॥10
            <br><br>
            सानन्दमानन्दवने वसन्तमानन्दकन्दं हतपापवृन्दम् ।
            <br>
            वाराणसीनाथमनाथनाथं श्रीविश्वनाथं शरणं प्रपद्ये ॥11
            <br><br>
            इलापुरे रम्यविशालकेऽस्मिन् समुल्लसन्तं च जगद्वरेण्यम् ।
            <br>
            वन्दे महोदारतरस्वभावं घृष्णेश्वराख्यं शरणम् प्रपद्ये ॥12
            <br><br>
            ज्योतिर्मयद्वादशलिङ्गकानां शिवात्मनां प्रोक्तमिदं क्रमेण ।
            <br>
            स्तोत्रं पठित्वा मनुजोऽतिभक्त्या फलं तदालोक्य निजं भजेच्च ॥13
            <br><br>
            ॥ इति द्वादश ज्योतिर्लिङ्गस्तोत्रं संपूर्णम् ॥
        </p>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Main end -->
    <!-- Js -->
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I had tried to set css property on audio to z-index +10 and the side panel z-index to +100 but it didn't work.

Comment: `<div/> </header>` - that's a typo there that needs fixing. I can't manage to reproduce the actual problem though, although that might be due to the fact that the code snippet functionality here, as well as jsfiddle or codepen, are problematic in terms of setting the `viewport` meta tag. Can you give the actual window width at which this is supposed to be problematic?

Comment: on mobile screens or page width less than 900px